# Is it possible to create a slightly different version of subscribe() method for angular 2 http?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-services

I am trying `angular2`. I found that we should use `subscribe()` method to retrive the result of `get` or `post` method:

```
this.http.post(path, item).subscribe(
  (response: Response)=> {console.log(response)},
  (error: any)=>{console.log(error)}
);
```

But I want to create a custom version of subscribe() method which has an error callback function that its error argument is not `any` and is strongly typed. Therefore we will be able to subscribe to the Observable in this way:

```
this.http.post(path, item).subscribe(
  (response: Response)=> {console.log(response)},
  (error: HttpError)=>{console.log(error.body)}
);
```

I declared `HttpError` as follows:

```
import { ModelState } from "app/Base/model-state";
import { ModelStateDictionary } from "app/Base/model-state-dictionary";
import { ErrorBody } from "app/Base/error-body";

export class HttpError {
    public ok: boolean;
    public status: number;
    public statusText: string;
    public type: number;
    public url: string;
    public body: ErrorBody;
    public static create(error: any): HttpError {
        let errorBody: ErrorBody = new ErrorBody();
        let body = JSON.parse(error._body)
        errorBody.message = body.message == null ? "" : body.message;
        errorBody.modelStateDictionary = new ModelStateDictionary();
        if (body.modelState != null) {
            for (let key in body.modelState) {
                let modelState: ModelState = new ModelState();
                modelState.Value = key;
                for (let value in body.modelState[key]) {
                    modelState.Error.push(value);
                }
                errorBody.modelStateDictionary.push(modelState);
            }
        }
        let httpError: HttpError = new HttpError();
        httpError.body = errorBody;
        httpError.ok = error.ok;
        httpError.status = error.status;
        httpError.statusText = error.statusText;
        httpError.type = error.type;
        httpError.url = error.url;
        return httpError;
    }
}
```

*But somewhere I need to call `create()` method before subscription, and convert the java object error to `HttpError`*. I guess I need to create a custom Observable or may be use `map()`. I am new to `TypeScript` and `Reactive programming`. Could you please explain me how can I do this conversion and therefore the user could use the better version of subscribe()?

Comment: The error block here is not for what you think it is for. You are looking for `response.status` since things like "4xx" and "5xx" status code are not actually an exception in this context. See [Response](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Response-class.html) in the Angular docs for more details

Comment: Your general confusion here is trying to delegate this to `.subscribe()`, which is a method that has nothing to do with the request. The [http](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html) service methods simply return an `Observable` of the `Response` class as noted above. Think of `Observable` like a "transport medium" as the `Response` it is carrying is what matters. An "exception" in the "error" here would be something like a socket connection fail or timeout.

Answer (score 1):

First, I believe http.post in Angular is just encapsulating the HTTP response. Below is from Angular source code.

```
function httpRequest(backend: ConnectionBackend, request: Request): Observable<Response> {
  return backend.createConnection(request).response;
}
```

Here either response or error is actually HTTP response object.

```
this.http.post(path, item).subscribe(
  (response: Response)=> {console.log(response)},
  (error: any)=>{console.log(error)}
);
```

I think you may extend a method you want in Observable to process the response and get the Object of your definition. Something like this.http.post(path, item).castHttpError().subscribe()

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/subscribe.md

However, I am not sure if this is safe as you are extending a reliable library. At least, Angular does not recommend developers to create his/her own distribution of Angular. You may have a try.

Last, I would suggest you write a utility method to implement this, which might be redundant but it does not hurt.

```
this.http.post(path, item).subscribe(
  response => { console.log(response); },
  error => {
    console.log(toHttpError(error).body);
  }
);
```